# limiting the number of table view cells that are dynamically drawn to the number of objects in the data source

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, tableview

How can I limit the number of cells that are drawn in my table view to the number of objects in my data source. Right now it displays my data, but it also displays empty cells underneath. how can I make it so that it does not draw any empty cells after it runs out of data to display.

Im using a storyboard with a tableView controller.

edit: found the answer

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: can you show your code for numberOfRowsInTableView: method

Comment: @martinR yeah I just found that post.